# Android open file

Tags: android, file

I was trying to open a file for reading.

When using: `Scanner input = new Scanner(filename);` the file could not be found

but when I used:

```
InputStream in = openFileInput(filename);
Scanner input = new Scanner(in);
```

It worked. Why was the first line of code wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Files are stored on the device in a specific, application-dependent location, which is what I suppose `openFileInput` adds at the beginning of the file name. The final result (location + file name) is constructed as follows:

```
/data/data/<application-package>/files/<file-name>
```

Note also that the documentation states that the `openFileInput` parameter [cannot contain path separators](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileInput%28java.lang.String%29).

To avoid hard-coding the location path, which could in principle even be different from device to device, you can obtain a `File` object pointing to the storage directory by calling `getFilesDir`, and use it to read whatever file you would like to. For example:

```
File filesDir = getFilesDir();
Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(filesDir, filename));
```

Note that constructing a `Scanner` by passing a `String` as a parameter would result in the scanner working on the content of the string, i.e. interpreting it as the actual content to scan instead of as the name of a file to open.

Comment: thank you!! i used the wrong constructor at the beginning :P..
then i tried to use Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(filename));
but it didnt work...
File filesDir = getFilesDir();
Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(filesDir, filename));
this works great:D

Answer (score 9):

This drove me crazy couple of minutes ago. I forgot to add this line to manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I would expect a *permission denied* message. But just got a *file not found*...

**In your case:** `openFileInput` opens a file in your private app data directory (`/data/data/your.package/filename`). This never fails. But the scanner tries to open it on the root path. So when you want to read a file from SD card than you would use `Environement.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + filename`.

Answer (score -6):

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(filename));
```

Comment: could you please provide more information? Throwing code around doesn't help anybody...