# Getting File object or URI object from android assets directory

Tags: android, assets

I must get a File object or a Uri object from android assets directory, but I only know how to get inputStream object.

Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Just use the search function:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7741804/android-open-file

Answer (score 2):

You cannot get a `File` object to an asset, as it is not a file on the device. It is a file in your development machine, but it is merely an entry in an APK file on the device.

Some things, like `WebView`, can work with a `file:///android_asset/...` `Uri`, where `...` is replaced by the relative path within `assets/` of your project to the file of interest. For example, if your project has `assets/index.html`, `file:///android_asset/index.html` would point to that file. AFAIK, not everything can use this sort of `Uri`, and in particular things that need a `URI` (e.g., `java.net`) probably cannot use it.

Comment: So the question was how do you do it.

Comment: @the_prole: And the answer is, "You cannot get a `File` object to an asset", as shown above.