# How can I open a file on an android device?

Tags: c, file, java-native-interface

I am trying to open a file in my application's data folder, on a physical device using adb.
I have placed a file in Android\data\com.myorg.myproject\files\image.jpg, and try to load it directly from the current directory, as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7741958/1974659).

```
extern "C" JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL method_signature
    (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
{
char filepath[200] = "image.jpg";
FILE *f = fopen(filepath,"rb");
if (f == NULL)
{
    LOGD("error could not open file"); // this line, unfortunately, executes.
    return ERROR;
}
return SUCCESS;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Should I use an absolute path, and how would the absolute filepath look like to be successful? Do I need something else (like permission from android to open a file in my own project files folder), to be able to open the file?

Comment: is it like `hardpath` and `filepath` meant to be same?

Comment: yes, i have fixed the snippet.

Comment: Why not pass the value of `getFilesDir` to your JNI function so that you can use that as the path?

Comment: Is the file in the current directory?